# Configure NGINX by passing CLI parameters instead of config file

Tags: nginx, command-line-interface, path, dynamic, options

I am looking for a way to change some config parameters dynamically before running NGINX. Perfectly by using command line parameters. I want to write a bash script that takes for example two parameters:

- root directory of files to be served,
- name of the php docker container to process php files.

These parameters are normally defined in config file:

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

files to be served:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
```

php parser:

```
fastcgi_pass php:9000;
```

Since they are hardcoded I need to create a specific configuration for every project I want to run with NGINX. I want to avoid that and have one bash script that reads CLI parameters and starts NGINX with them.

I could not find any other [NGINX CLI Parameters](https://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html) than these and did not find a suitable candidates to achieve my goal. Maybe there are other CLI parameters I could use, maybe I could use environmental variable inside **default.conf** so values of **root** and **fastcgi_pass** aren't hardcoded, or maybe there is a plugin that could provide additional CLI parameters to NGINX?

I'm running official Docker images of [NGINX 1.15](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) and [PHP-FPM 7.3](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) via my bash script that uses `docker run` commands to set everything up.

Comment: nginx configuration is far too complex to be done on the command line, so only a very few (simple) options are usable. You are free to write your own configuration generator to meet your specific needs, though, or better yet, use container-aware configuration management such as Ansible/Ansible Container.